# Is there a way to determine which nodes in my Cassandra cluster are being use as coordinators?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I have a couple of nodes that are hotter than the rest.
I would like to confirm that my driver is sending requests to multiple nodes.  I would like to know who is doing the coordination task.

Answer (score 1):

Can use JMX (tools like [sjk](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools)) and read the `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=[Read/Write],name=Latency` mbeans `Count` attribute.

Alternatively can check `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=CQL,name=RegularStatementsExecuted` and `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=CQL,name=PreparedStatementsExecuted`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the client to verify, several drivers have ways of getting the coordinator. Check here for the Java driver:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#getExecutionInfo--
http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ExecutionInfo.html#getQueriedHost--
http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ExecutionInfo.html#getTriedHosts--